# django Formset won't save

Tags: django, formset

I have the below view for a Formset, but when I save the form it doesn't save changes to the database?

```
def schedule(request, year, month, day):
     EntriesFormset = modelformset_factory(Entry, extra = 1, exclude=("creator",   "date"),can_delete=True)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = EntriesFormset(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
        # add current user and date to each entry & save
            entries = formset.save(commit=False)
            for entry in entries:
                entry.creator = request.user
                entry.date = date(int(year), int(month), int(day))
                entry.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("Pipettes.views.month", args=(year, month)))

    else:
    # display formset for existing enties and one extra form
        formset = EntriesFormset(queryset=Entry.objects.filter(date__year=year,date__month=month, creator=request.user))
    return render_to_response("Scheduler.html", add_csrf(request, entries=formset, year=year,
        month=month, day=day))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the formset is invalid but instead of displaying of the formset with errors you returning the redirect.  You should move the redirecting to one level right, into the `if` statement:

```
if formset.is_valid():
    ...
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("Pipettes.views.month", args=(year, month)))
```

**UPDATE**: If your formset is not validated but you don't see any errors on the page then your formset rendering may be invalid.  For testing purposes try to use the simplest possible template:

```
<table>
    {{ formset }}
</table>
```

Also note that with `formset.save(commit=False)` deleted objects are not deleted automatically.  See the side note in [this chapter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/#can-delete) of the docs.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I moved to the right under the for statement, but it still doesn't work

Comment: "Doesn't work" means formset is valid, `entries` is not empty but they not saved before the redirecting?

Comment: How can I check what is wrong with the formset since it is not valid? Thanks!

Comment: If I enter new data into the form or try to delete old data, there are no changes to the database and it doens't redirect, it just stays on the that page

Comment: I figured it out!! Thank you so much! I figured out why my formset wasn't valid!! :)

Comment: @ecw1014 Can you explain to me how did you figure it? I still have these problem!

Comment: can you please explain